# Matrix Library for .NET

Tags: .net, math, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm looking for a good (well-tested, fully-featured, and ideally with a nice interface) matrix library for .NET/C#. My main requirements here are only that it should be free (I don't particularly care whether it's open-source in this case) and preferably support [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) operations. The obligatory requirements are all the basic operations (e.g. multiplication, transposition, inversion) as well as finding eigenvalues & eigenvectors. Implementation of a numerical rather than/as well as analytical methods for discovery of eigenvalues, particularly the [Lanczos algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) for sparse matrices, would be highly preferable since the matrices I'm going to be dealing with are very large (lengths of 10,000 upwards) as well as square, and also reasonably sparse. Saying that, I could be asking for a bit much there, so any suggestions for a reasonably complete matrix library would be great.

Now I'm aware that Python has one or two useful libraries for such tasks (namely [NumPy](https://numpy.org/)/[SciPy](https://scipy.org/)), but .NET unfortunately seems to be lacking in the area.

A bit of searching turned up the following libraries for .NET, which I could potentially used:

- Lutz Roeder's [Mapack](https://web.archive.org/web/20180610232503/https://github.com/lutzroeder/Mapack)
- [DotNetMatrix](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5835/DotNetMatrix-Simple-Matrix-Library-for-NET) (CodeProject)
- [C# Matrix Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20100612063158/http://www.codeproject.com:80/KB/cs/CSML.aspx) (CodeProject)

However, since I have had no experience whatsoever using any of these libraries or others (and not exactly enough time to check each of them out properly in any case), I would very much appreciate if anyone here could discuss their recommendations regarding the various libraries, their pros/cons particularly with regards to suitability for my uses, and their general experiences with them.

Resorting to MatLab is always an option, but not a preferred one, as it would be much more convenient if I could integrate the matrix math directly with my program.

Comment: So telling that there's still no progress on this issue on 3-Dec-2022.  Open source for Microsoft languages has never come close to that for Java or Python and is unlikely to ever do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit:

It wasn't quite there last time I evaluated it, but there has been quite a bit of activity, so you should also consider the (free and open source) [Math.NET Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/).

In looking now, it seems they've finished their new version, and have added sparse matrix support, as well as other nice goodies.

---

If you want more robust support, you unfortunately really need to get into commercial packages for .NET atm.

There are two very feature-rich packages, both of which support matrices very well.  [Extreme Numerics](https://web.archive.org/web/20221127131225/https://www.extremeoptimization.com/) works great, and has some very nice features. I've also heard very good things about the [IMSL Visual Numerics](https://web.archive.org/web/20141018050549/http://www.roguewave.com:80/products/imsl-numerical-libraries.aspx) math libraries.

Comment: Yeah, I've been starting to suspect you're right. Commercial packages aren't really an option I'm afraid, my being a university student. Still, thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: @Noldorin: I'd write to Jeremy at extreme numerics and ask if he could provide you a research license since you're a student, and it's not being used commercially.  It's a small company, and the owner seems fairly friendly and responsive.  (He's been great for support, pre-sales, etc.)  It can't hurt.  ;)

Comment: @Noldorin: I just remember dnAnalytics, and added it, too.  It's probably the best non-commercial option.

Comment: @Reed: Great find there with dnAnalytics. :) I agree, it looks easily better than Mapack, especially given the support for sparse matrices. I'm very tempted to go with that now, and either implement the Lanczos algorithm on top or at worst export the matrix to Matlab and get it to do that for me. If none of that works out, I could definitely try getting in touch with Jeremy at Extreme Numerics.

Comment: @Reed: Thank you for the continued suggestions and comments. The answer is yours. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try [ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net): We have a rel. long history as open source project and recently changed to commercial licenses for better and reliable support. I am biased but here comes a short feature list:

- Better memory management, hence ...
- Much faster algorithms
- Uses MKL for linear algebra
- n-dim array classes, syntax similar to Matlab
- 3D plot controls
- Support for 32/64 bit
- Support for mono
- [Full feature list](http://ilnumerics.net/%24FeatureList.html)

Answer (score 2):

I have us Mapack in the past and found it to be very good.

Although, I don't think it has Sparse matrices but it does support all the basic linear algegra functions.

Comment: Yeah, there don't seem to be any with support for sparse matrices. Still, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative: [IMSL for .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20081203122804/http://www.vni.com./products/imsl/cSharp/overview.php).  CenterSpace has the [NMath](https://www.centerspace.net/product-overviews) libraries -- haven't used these.

Comment: Those are both commercial, it seems. It's a shame, because they seem like rather good libraries...

Comment: @Noldorin: I did a pretty thorough search in the .NET space a while back.  All of the good, robust matrix libs are pretty much commercial (at least as of early 2008).

Comment: @Reed: Yeah, that wouldn't surprise me at all... I'll take your word for it anyway. I'm wondering if using the Mapack library and implementing the Lanczos algorithm over it might do the job however.

Comment: @Noldorin: I actually think dnAnalytics is nicer then Mapack in the .NET world - see my edit for links.

Answer (score 1):

I used Mapack (the .Net port not the COM version) in a neural network project at university. I can't exactly remember the fine details of the library, but it did everything I needed it to and wasn't particularly onerous to use.

Comment: Consensus seems to be (at least judging by two of the answers and the bit I've read elsewhere) that Mapack is the way to go as far as free libs, even though it isn't perfect. I'm also using matrix functionality for a university project, though it's physics-based one, so as long as I get the results out somehow it doesn't matter too much about the method. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Meta.Numerics](https://web.archive.org/web/20221009203053/http://meta-numerics.net/) (hosted on [codeplex](https://web.archive.org/web/20180117002406/http://metanumerics.codeplex.com:80/)) is a free package that will compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of non-symmetric matrices, but it does not currently treat sparse matrices specially.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll probably still go with dnAnalytics, as it can handle sparse matrices well, but that looks like a useful general-purpose library to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

have you considered math.net iridium ?

http://iridium.mathdotnet.com/

Answer (score 0):

The now-defunct Managed DirectX library had some matrix support.

That has since been wrapped into Microsoft XNA, which is probably not a good fit for you, but the [MDX Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_DirectX) recommends something called [SlimDX](http://ww38.slimdx.mdxinfo.com/) that [might be okay](https://web.archive.org/web/20110609234944/http://slimdx.org:80/latestdocs/Help/Html/T_SlimDX_Matrix.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately, they're not really options for me given that they only support up to 4x4 matrices in size! I'm afraid I need something that can handle matrices with 1000s of rows/columns, and ideally handle sparse ones efficiently (when it comes to multiplication for example).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding .NET and Python, you could use IronPython.  However, you'll also need [Ironclad](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/03/19/ironclad-ironpytho/) to make SciPy and NumPy work with IronPython.