# Joining Two 2D String Arrays

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I have two 2D string arrays:

```
string[,] stringArray1 = {
                 {name1, name2, name3, name4, name5}, 
                 {value1, value2, value3, value4, value5}};

string[,] stringArray2 = {
                 {name1, name3, name5, name2, name4}, 
                 {defaultvalue1, defaultvalue3, defaultvalue5, 
                  defaultvalue2, defaultvalue4}};
```

Is there a way to join these two string arrays:

```
stringArrayJOINED = {
                  {name1, name2, name3, name4, name5}, 
                  {value1, value2, value3, value4, value5}, 
                  {defaultvalue1, defaultvalue2, defaultvalue3, 
                   defaultvalue4, defaultvalue5}};
```

NOTE: All name fields are unique.

Thanks in advance for any help! =)

Comment: Try this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711130/concatenate-a-2d-array

Comment: The fact that they are arrays of strings is irrelavent. Why are you using multi dimensional arrays in the first place? They are not helping you much here.

Comment: Why wouldn't you merge them as:

stringArrayJOINED = {{name1, name2, name3, name4, name5}, {value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, defaultvalue1, defaultvalue2, defaultvalue3, defaultvalue4, defaultvalue5}};

Does each group have some kind of special signature that tells you what group it belongs in?

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do is match up two string arrays that are made from looping through two different XML docs. Since the docs are in different orders, I want to order them on the Name value, which I have designated to be stored in the first row of each array. I am essentially trying to do something like a SQL JOIN ON name. I just don't know how to do this in C#.

Comment: How are you populating these arrays originally? I'd suggest using a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` over an array if possible. The key would be the Name, and the dictionary value would be a list of values from your docs.

Comment: Dont you want an array of array ([][]) rather than a 2d array ([,])?

Comment: @Magnus Well, he really doesn't want either, he wants these collections to be Dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by converting the MDs into somthing more useful,

```
var dic1 =
   Enumerable.Range(stringArray1.GetLowerBound(1), stringArray1.GetUpperBound(1))
   .ToDictionary(
        i => stringArray1[0, i], 
        i => stringArray1[1, i]);

var dic2 =
   Enumerable.Range(stringArray2.GetLowerBound(1), stringArray2.GetUpperBound(1))
   .ToDictionary(
        i => stringArray2[0, i], 
        i => stringArray2[1, i]);
```

Then,

```
var trios = dic1.Keys.Select(
                k => new { Key = k, Value = dic1[k], Default = dic2[k] });
```

Then, if you really feel the need ...

```
var trioList = trios.ToList();
var stringArrayJOINED = new string[3, trioList.Count];
for (var i = 0; i < trioList.Count; i++)
{
    stringArrayJoined[0, i] = trioList[i].Key;
    stringArrayJoined[1, i] = trioList[i].Value;
    stringArrayJoined[2, i] = trioList[i].Default;
}
```

---

If the default values are sparsely populated, which it sounds like they are, combine like  this,

```
var robustButDirtyTrios = dic1.Keys.Select(k =>
                new 
                    { 
                        Key = k, 
                        Value = dic1[k], 
                        Default = dic2.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == k) 
                    });
```

then convert to the MDA like this,

```
var trioList = robustButDirtyTrios.ToList();
var stringArrayJOINED = new string[3, trioList.Count];
for (var i = 0; i < trioList.Count; i++)
{
    stringArrayJoined[0, i] = trioList[i].Key;
    stringArrayJoined[1, i] = trioList[i].Value;
    var defaultValue = trioList[i].Default;
    if (defaultValue != null)
    {
        stringArrayJoined[2, i] = default; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You've been around long enough to know that you shouldn't post works in progress.  You need to wait until your answer actually answers the question to post is.  Posting a non-answer as a placeholder before your answer is done is not appropriate behavior.  If it was an accident that you posted it early, it would have been best to just delete it until you finished developing it, then undelete.

Comment: Why is it bad to convert it back to a String[,]? Ultimately, I want to pass it to a SQL Command and the String[] is an easy way for me to organize the data and loop through it to do the Parameters.AddWithValue functions. Can I do this with it as a dictionary? Is it as simple?

Comment: @IanBest It's just as easy to do with a dictionary as with a string array.  Easier in fact, because you can deal with each pair in isolation through a `foreach`.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Also, I got an error on var trios = dic1.Keys.Select(k=> new { Key = k, Value = dic1[k], Default = dic2[k] }); It says that The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: @IanBest I'd prefer a list of a type, similar to the anonymous one I've created in the middle of my answer. Then I could access the values using named properties rather than an arbritary index. It would also work better with any linq I wanted to write later.

Comment: @Jodrell What? I'm sorry, you lost me. Was that response addressing my error?

Comment: @IanBest If you're getting that error it means your data isn't as well formed as the question would lead us to believe.  It means that not all of the keys in the first set are found in the second set.  Jordrell's answer didn't account for that, by my solution was specifically designed to work in that situation.

Comment: @Jodrell I copied and pasted from this post just to get a decent understanding of the inner workings. I am using this data exactly.

Answer (score 2):

So your real problem here is that you're using a two dimensional array to store mappings between values.  That is not a very good data structure for that.  A `Dictionary` or `Lookup` is much more effective as it logically represents a collection of keys that each map to a value, although it would be good enough in your case to have a list or sequence of an object that holds both a key and a value:

Before doing anything here is a handy helper method for getting the row of a two dimensional array out as a sequence; we'll use it later:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetRow<T>(this T[,] array, int rowIndex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        yield return array[rowIndex, i];
    }
}
```

Now we can easily map the two arrays into sequences of pairs:

```
var firstLookup = stringArray1.GetRow(0)
    .Zip(stringArray1.GetRow(1), (a, b) => new { Key = a, Value = b });

var secondLookup = stringArray2.GetRow(0)
    .Zip(stringArray2.GetRow(1), (a, b) => new { Key = a, Value = b });
```

Once we have this we can join the two sequences using the LINQ `GroupJoin` operator:

```
var finalLookup = firstLookup.GroupJoin(secondLookup, pair => pair.Key
        , pair => pair.Key
        , (pair, matches) => new { pair, matches })
    .ToDictionary(results => results.pair.Key
        , results => new[] { results.pair.Value }.Concat(
            results.matches.Select(group => group.Value)));
```

(You could use `Join` instead of `GroupJoin` if you were sure that no keys are duplicated, but this is just as easy and would properly handle additional cases.)

The end result is a lookup in which there is a key for every name in either of your sequences that maps to a value; that value is a sequence of string which represents all of the values for that key (in your case, it will always be a sequence of size two).

You could convert this back into a two dimensional array if you *really* need to, but it will be much harder to use if you do.

Comment: This will sound like a retort but anyway, you don't show how to convert back to the multidimensional array. I agree that you wouldn't want to but ...

Comment: I intentionally omitted it.  In the event that the OP indicates that it is truly necessary, I may choose to edit such as solution in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This looks great. One quick question, though: GetRow() from the second code block is erroring. I looked on MSDN for a similar method, but don't know which would replicate the GetRow functionality exactly. Is there one? Thanks, again. Much appreciated.

Comment: The answer will work for no or many matches between the keys which is good but could be interesting if you did want to convert to a Multi Dimensional array. +1

Comment: @Jodrell Yeah, if you wanted to fix the fact that each key is in each input set exactly once then you would use `Join`, not `GroupJoin`, which would fix the result matches to exactly two, not N, making a conversion to an array easier.  To convert this to an array you'd need to assume all result sets were of the same size.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
stringArrayJoined = stringArray1.Concat(stringArray2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the resposne. Will this account for them being out of order? Will it match on the name1-name5 field?

Comment: it keeps the order of the two arrays:
all elements in array1, then all elements in array2

Comment: This is going to just concat the 2 arrays, and will duplicate the `name` items. He's wanting to match the values of each `name` item with each value in the arrays.