# C# wrapper for a Python piece of code

Tags: c#, python, interface, numpy, wrapper

Is it much struggle to write a C# wrapper for some existing Python function ? I would like to use numpy methods in a C# code, binding python code to C# code.

I am sorry there are not so many details, no excerpt, ...

Kind regards ;  )

Comment: Is [IronPython](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumPy%20and%20SciPy%20for%20.Net) an option?

Comment: NumPy and SciPy have been [ported to .NET](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumPy%20and%20SciPy%20for%20.Net).

Comment: Although you could also consider just using a [.NET matrix library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840360/matrix-library-for-net).